# FileUpload Jquery com C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, upload

estou com o seguinte problema

Estou utilizando MVC (C#) e preciso fazer um Upload de documentos em geral(.doc, .pdf , .png, etc)

Estou utilizando a biblioteca FileUpload e com jquery 3.1

No padrão de exemplo que o componente tem, é o jquery 1.9(não sei se pode ter algo a ver) e funciona normalmente.

Recebo o erro abaixo

> TypeError: $(...).fileupload is not a function

o código em si da pagina esta abaixo

```html
<p>
    <input type="text" id="tbx-file-path" value="No file chosen..." readonly="readonly" />

    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
        <span>Select file...</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyFile, new { id = "fu-my-simple-upload", type = "file" })
    </span>
</p>
<p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" id="hl-start-upload">Start Upload</a></p>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var jqXHRData;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            'use strict';

            $('#fu-my-simple-upload').fileupload({
                url: '/File/UploadFile',
                dataType: 'json',
                add: function (e, data) {
                    jqXHRData = data
                },
                done: function (event, data) {
                    if (data.result.isUploaded) {
                        $("#tbx-file-path").val("No file chosen...");
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                    alert(data.result.message);
                },
                fail: function (event, data) {
                    if (data.files[0].error) {
                        alert(data.files[0].error);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $("#hl-start-upload").on('click', function () {
            if (jqXHRData) {
                jqXHRData.submit();
            }
            return false;
        });

        $("#fu-my-simple-upload").on('change', function () {
            $("#tbx-file-path").val(this.files[0].name);
        });

    </script>
}
```

Comment: Me parece que a biblioteca do File Uploader não foi carregada.

Comment: Sim. Porém ela está no projeto

Comment: Veja se as bibliotecas estão na ordem correta, de cima pra baixo. O jQuery vem antes de todas.

Comment: Todas as bibliotecas estão OK.
Estou checando para ver se não tem algum tipo de conflito de arquivos jquery